# Rails 3.1 nested_form gem no response to add link_to_add and link_to_remove

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model, nested-forms

i want to add and remove a model to my parent model. everything is working fine except that the add and remove button dont work. while hovering in link to add it shows javascript:void(o).

below is my code,

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %> 
<%= f.fields_for :stops do |task_form| %>
<%= task_form.text_field :address %>
<%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a stop", :stops %></p>
<p><%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**post.rb**

```
has_many :stops    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stops, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:address].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

**posts_controller**

```
def new
@post = Post.new
@post.stops.new
end
```

i would be greatful if some could help me
cheers

Comment: formatting hint: just use 4 spaces each line that should be code and additional 4 spaces for indent. Question stays how you want to format the post.rb, I didn't figure out.